# Magento manager Customer DB Table Structure

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I want to Create New Customer from Adempiere to Magento .

Can Anyone give me the Customer DB Table and column Structure

Customer and Customer Address details Tables Are:

- Customer_Entity
- Customer Entity Varchar
- Customer Address Entity
- Customer Address Entity Varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to use the Magento's own APIs to create customer. Here is a small example. You can add further attributes by looking at Magento customer API documentation.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId = $websiteId;
$customer->setStore($store);

$customer->setFirstname($afirstname);
$customer->setLastname($alastname);
$customer->setEmail($email);
$customer->setPasswordHash(md5($password));
$customer->save();



$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");              
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId());
$address->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname());
$address->setLastname($customer->getLastname());
$address->setCountryId($country); //Country code here
$address->setStreet($street);
$address->setPostcode($postcode);
$address->setCity($city);
$address->setTelephone($telephone);
$address->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Magento archive database dumps at http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-archive-database-dumps-structure-only-data-only-full/